# What other ways are there to obtain sector data?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

While playing FTL, I have suddenly gained information on the sector without having Long-Range Scanners or having paid a mercenary for a scouting report. IE, I can see environmental hazards and potential ship locations.

It has happened a few times, on different playthroughs. When it happens, it lasts for the duration of the sector, and then goes away.

Is there an event (other than paying mercs to scout), or something else that triggers this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Occasionally, you will get this as a reward for certian encounters.  One that springs to mind is map data for encountering a lone drone without destroying it (requires an Engi, I believe), but other encounters can also update your map data and reveal information to you as a reward.

Comment: yep, there are more ways than just long range scanners or paying a merc to get data on a sector.

Answer (score 7):

As Zibbobz brought out, here are several random events which reward you with map data.

I haven't found a complete list on the wiki, but a quick search revealed just a few of many random events which reward you with map data of the sector.

- [De-Activated Rebel Automated Scout Random Mission](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/De-Activated_Rebel_Automated_Scout_Random_Mission)
- [Rebel Automated Ship Near Sensor Station](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Rebel_Automated_Ship_Near_Sensor_Station)
- [Drone guardian Rebel station](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Drone_guardian_Rebel_station)
- [Federation Deserters](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Federation_Deserters)
- [Zoltan Ship Tour](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Zoltan_Ship_Tour)

Most of them follow the same pattern of receiving the map data after defeating a ship, but a few have other requirements such as upgraded sensors, or (just like in the case of merchants) receiving the map data in exchange for resources.